# How to Modify a cell/s value based on a condition in Pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, sql-update

I have a dataframe which has a few columns like below :

```
 category| category_id|    bucket| prop_count| event_count |   accum_prop_count |  accum_event_count
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
nation  |   nation     |    1     | 222       |     444     |   555              |  6677
```

This dataframe starts from 0 rows and each function of my script adds a row to this.

There is a function which needs to modify 1 or 2 cell values based on condition. How to do this?

Code:

```
schema = StructType([StructField("category", StringType()), StructField("category_id", StringType()), StructField("bucket", StringType()), StructField("prop_count", StringType()), StructField("event_count", StringType()), StructField("accum_prop_count",StringType())])
a_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([],schema)

a_temp = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("nation","nation",1,222,444,555)],schema)
a_df = a_df.unionAll(a_temp)
```

Rows added from some other function:

```
a_temp3 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("nation","state",2,222,444,555)],schema)
a_df = a_df.unionAll(a_temp3)
```

Now to modify, I am trying a join with a condition.

```
a_temp4 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("state","state",2,444,555,666)],schema)
a_df = a_df.join(a_temp4, [(a_df.category_id == a_temp4.category_id) & (some other cond here)], how = "inner")
```

But this code is not working. I am getting an error:

```
+--------+-----------+------+----------+-----------+----------------+--------+-----------+------+----------+-----------+----------------+
|category|category_id|bucket|prop_count|event_count|accum_prop_count|category|category_id|bucket|prop_count|event_count|accum_prop_count|
+--------+-----------+------+----------+-----------+----------------+--------+-----------+------+----------+-----------+----------------+
|  nation|      state|     2|       222|        444|             555|   state|      state|     2|       444|        555|             666|
+--------+-----------+------+----------+-----------+----------------+--------+-----------+------+----------+-----------+----------------+
```

How to fix this? Correct output should have 2 rows and the second row should have an updated value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1). An inner join will delete rows from your initial dataframe, if you want to have the same number of lines as `a_df`(on the left) you need a left join.

2). an `==` condition will duplicate columns if your columns have the same names you can use a list instead.

3). I imagine "some other condition" refers to `bucket`

4). You want to keep the value from a_temp4 if it exists (the join will set its values at null if it doesn't), `psf.coalesce` allows you to do this

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
a_df = a_df.join(a_temp4, ["category_id", "bucket"], how="leftouter").select(
    psf.coalesce(a_temp4.category, a_df.category).alias("category"), 
    "category_id", 
    "bucket", 
    psf.coalesce(a_temp4.prop_count, a_df.prop_count).alias("prop_count"), 
    psf.coalesce(a_temp4.event_count, a_df.event_count).alias("event_count"), 
    psf.coalesce(a_temp4.accum_prop_count, a_df.accum_prop_count).alias("accum_prop_count")
    )

+--------+-----------+------+----------+-----------+----------------+
|category|category_id|bucket|prop_count|event_count|accum_prop_count|
+--------+-----------+------+----------+-----------+----------------+
|   state|      state|     2|       444|        555|             666|
|  nation|     nation|     1|       222|        444|             555|
+--------+-----------+------+----------+-----------+----------------+
```

If you only work with one-line dataframes you should consider coding the update directly instead of using join:

```py
def update_col(category_id, bucket, col_name, col_val):
    return psf.when((a_df.category_id == category_id) & (a_df.bucket == bucket), col_val).otherwise(a_df[col_name]).alias(col_name)

a_df.select(
    update_col("state", 2, "category", "nation"), 
    "category_id", 
    "bucket", 
    update_col("state", 2, "prop_count", 444), 
    update_col("state", 2, "event_count", 555), 
    update_col("state", 2, "accum_prop_count", 666)
).show()
```